# CustomFormatProvider not being invoked

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following implementation of `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter`

```csharp
using System;
using System.Globalization;

internal class LoggingFormatProvider : IFormatProvider
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        var isNumberFormatInfo = formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo):  {0}", isNumberFormatInfo);
        if (isNumberFormatInfo)
        {
            return new MyNumberFormatter();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class MyNumberFormatter : ICustomFormatter
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var replaced = arg.ToString()
            .Replace("1", "One")
            .Replace("2", "Two")
            .Replace("3", "Three")
            .Replace("4", "Four")
            .Replace("5", "Five")
            .Replace("6", "Six")
            .Replace("7", "Seven")
            .Replace("8", "Eight")
            .Replace("9", "Nine")
            .Replace("0", "Zero");

        Console.WriteLine("Returning: {0}", replaced);
        return replaced;
    }
}
```

I'm invoking it like this:

```csharp
private static void Main()
{
    var myLoggingProvider = new LoggingFormatProvider();
    Console.WriteLine("Using string.Format()");
    var s = string.Format(myLoggingProvider, "123: {0:X}", 123);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine("  Returned: {0}", s);
}
```

When I run it, `MyNumberFormatter.Format` isn't called and instead the default number formatter is (formatting `123` as hex `7B`);

It outputs:

```
Using string.Format()
formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo):  False
formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo):  True
123: 7B
  Returned: 123: 7B
```

---

I get the same behavior if the `MyLoggingFormatter` type also implements the `ICustomFormatter` like so:

```csharp
internal class LoggingFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        var isNumberFormatInfo = formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo):  {0}", isNumberFormatInfo);
        if (isNumberFormatInfo)
        {
            //return new MyNumberFormatter();
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var replaced = arg.ToString()
            .Replace("1", "One")
            .Replace("2", "Two")
            // etc...
            .Replace("0", "Zero");

        Console.WriteLine("Returning: {0}", replaced);
        return replaced;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mate Aye, same behavior if I copy the `ICustomFormatter` implementation to the `LoggingFormatProvider`.

Comment: Why do you expect formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo) to be true?

Comment: @Dani because I'm passing an integer for formatting.  That conditional does return `true`.

Comment: If I run your code formatType is of type System.ICustomFormatter therefore it's false

Comment: @Dani First it's `ICustomFormatter`, then it's `NumberFormatInfo`.  It's invoked twice.

Comment: If you change your comparison to formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) Format gets called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

The `formatType` is the type that the is required for this formatting.  Therefore, if it's an `ICustomFormatter` then I need to return an `ICustomFormatter`, if it's a `NumberFormatInfo` then I need to return a `NumberFormatInfo`.

Given that `NumberFormatInfo` is a sealed class, it's not actually possible to make a custom one; therefore **all** custom formats, regardless of whether they target numbers, dates or *other* need to be `ICustomFormatter`.

If they don't match then it looks like the implementation just falls back to it's default.  It means that the examples on MSDN are actually misleading, the conditional check isn't needed, you can just return the implementation of `ICustomFormatter` and the framework will use it if it can.

(Obviously, you might want the conditional there just to reduce the number of allocations.)

Given the current CTS, there are only three possible values for `formatType`:

1. `NumberFormatInfo`
2. `DateTimeFormatInfo`
3. `ICustomFormatter`

If you're passed either of the first, you must return null because you can't construct a custom one, so let the framework pick the correct instance.

If you're passed the third, you can go custom-crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
var isNumberFormatInfo = formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo);
```

to this:

```
var isNumberFormatInfo = formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Aye.  The missing bit of information for me was that the returned type had to match the type being passed into the method.